# Free mail server support multiple IP for windows

Tags: windows, email, email-server

I am using hmailserver, its good mail server but only support one IP on my server. do you khnow any FREE mail server support multiple IP for outgoing emails?

mail.example.com : 1.1.1.1 mail2.example.com : 1.1.1.2

smartermail support this, but its not free for multiple domain

Comment: This is a shopping question which is off-topic here (see the [FAQ]).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your actual needs, the free version of Axigen Mail Server might be suitable.
It has the ability to create listeners for different IPs using it's admin interface.

http://www.axigen.com

Comment: its not windows mail server

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean, Axigen is supported on Windows:
http://www.axigen.com/mail-server/download/
http://www.axigen.com/mail-server/features/#aPlatforms

Answer (score 1):

Just use the integrated smtp server bundled with Windows.

http://www.itsolutionskb.com/2008/11/installing-and-configuring-windows-server-2008-smtp-server/

Comment: can i receive email with this mail server?

Comment: It can. But you can use one server for ingoing, and another for outgoing. Or you use hmailserver for both, but he pipes to the integrated mail server for outgoing.